# EXPO - OTA is still working even update.enable=false

Tags: react-native, expo, ota

Even I set updates.enable=false in app.json, still clients getting updated versions from expo server automatically (without deploying apk/ios to store’s).
I set updates.enable=false in version 1.1.7. Clients with version 1.1.7, 1.1.8 and 1.1.9 got 1.2.0 version automatically without putting new version (1.2.0) into store(s).

I’m using expo build:android and expo build:ios commands for build.

Could anyone can help me about this problem? Is there any way to prevent update on code level?

You can find my app.json content below:

```
{
“expo”: {
“name”: “XXX”,
“slug”: “XXX”,
“privacy”: “public”,
“sdkVersion”: “31.0.0”,
“platforms”: [
“ios”,
“android”
],
“version”: “1.2.0”,
“orientation”: “portrait”,
“icon”: “./assets/icon.png”,
“splash”: {
“image”: “./assets/icon.png”,
“resizeMode”: “contain”,
“backgroundColor”: “#FFCB09”
},
“notification”: {
“icon”: “./assets/icon96gs.png”,
“color”: “#ffcd00”,
“androidMode”: “collapse”,
“androidCollapsedTitle”: “XXX”
},
“updates”: {
“enabled”:false
},
“assetBundlePatterns”: [
“**/*”
],
“android”:{
“package”:“com.xxx.yyy”,
“permissions” : [“CAMERA”, “LOCATION_HARDWARE”,“ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION”,“ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION”],
“versionCode”: 17
},
“ios”: {
“bundleIdentifier”: “com.xxx.yyyt”,
“buildNumber” : “17”
},
“scheme” : “xxx”
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should upload your app in apple store and google play store. only after that updates will be switched off.

Comment: Does it means that we should let the flag set at `true` 24/7 to be sure that we can do an OTA update and then once this flag set at true, create a condition to use it or not ?

Answer (score -1):

Because you created a stand-alone app with Expokit, the commands in the setup do not apply.

You have to set up your own settings in Android Studio and xcode.

> "updates"

Configuration for how and when the app should request OTA JavaScript updates

```
{
  "updates": {
    /*
      If set to false, your standalone app will never download any code.
      And will only use code bundled locally on the device.
      In that case, all updates to your app must be submitted through Apple review.
      Defaults to true.

      Note that this will not work out of the box with ExpoKit projects.
    */
    "enabled": BOOLEAN,
   ...
}
```

**ExpoKit:** To change the value of enabled, edit ios//Supporting/EXShell.plist and android/app/src/main/java/host/exp/exponent/generated/AppConstants.java. All other properties are set at runtime.

Comment: For me this isn't clear enough. What am I supposed to write in my ExShell.plist exactly? It contains only key value pairs and there is no "enabled" at all.

Comment: In the case of `iOS`, I don't know yet either. So I'm calling a function from `App.js`. `Updates.checkForUpdateAsync()` This asks if you want to update.